# SKOverlay equivalent in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-play, admob

Is there any equivalent to SKOverlay on Android? My goal is to cross-promote the installation of my other applications and I would like to provide a recommended installation option without having to exit the app (or at least showing a popup), with an inline button.

The idea is achieve something like that (from Admob ads):

[image]

I don't know if this kind of views are accesible for developers or is just something Google makes for internal use

Comment: How is your image not a pop-up / modal view? You may want to review the component names/types: https://m3.material.io/components to find something desirable

Answer (score 2):

Yes, to achieve this you should make an [Instant app](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant) within you r app

[then using Instant apps sdk](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/instantapps/package-summary) you achieve something similar.

Example:

[image]